# Whats the point in calling app.Run() multiple times in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

`App.Use` can/should call the next middle ware. OK.

`App.Run` is terminal, no other middleware is executed after that. OK

WHY then have multiple calls to `App.Run` in succession ?? Sure, one uses the parameterized overload, but why does `App.Run(...)` need to be followd by `App.Run` ?? Does it make any sense ?? Or is it simply convention to always have `App.Run()` at the end even if its never reached ???

From [MS Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-7.0):

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var app = builder.Build();

app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    // Do work that can write to the Response.
    await next.Invoke();
    // Do logging or other work that doesn't write to the Response.
});

app.Run(async context =>
{
    await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello from 2nd delegate.");
}); <-- WE ALREADY HAVE THIS... ???

app.Run(); // <-- WHY THIS ???
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In ASP.NET Core 6, Microsoft introduced `WebApplication`, an attempt to simplify and unify setup and such for running a web app. `WebApplication` [implements both `IHost` and `IApplicationBuilder`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/001af9cf1aeae1f8e17ecc638f138f1cfda02a75/src/DefaultBuilder/src/WebApplication.cs#L21), both of which have existed from the earliest days in ASP.NET Core. As you've seen, both of these interfaces include a `Run` extension method of some form:

- [`IApplicationBuilder.Run`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.hostingabstractionshostextensions.run?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0):

  > Adds a terminal middleware delegate to the application's request pipeline.
- [`IHost.Run`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.runextensions.run?view=aspnetcore-7.0):

  > Runs an application and blocks the calling thread until host shutdown is triggered and all `IHostedService` instances are stopped.

The preceding descriptions (taken from the linked docs) show that the functions do very different things. Before the unification of `WebApplication`, these two methods were more obviously separate, as one was called in `Program.cs` on an `IHost` and the other was called in `Startup.Configure` on an `IApplicationBuilder`.

Answer (score 1):

OK, after testing I know now, that the application simply wont run (or at least immediately stops) if not calling `app.Run()` at the end. Despite its similar names, those two methods seem to do very different things.

1. Adding terminal middleware
2. Actually running the server

[App.Run()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev16.query?appId=Dev16IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.WebApplication.Run);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true)

> Runs an application and block the calling thread until host shutdown.

The similarity of the name is VERY CONFUSING!